# How to read the current terminal content programmatically?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to read the current terminal content (visible window, or full buffer, whatever it's easier) programmatically?

I need this because I'm trying to develop a program which, *after* executing an arbitrary command, works with its output. I stress *after* - I know pipes are used for this, but the purpose of the program is avoiding that.

A possible solution would be a combination of a programmatic `Select all` followed by an `xsel` invocation, although I don't know any way to perform the first operation [in Gnome Terminal].

Comment: Would it work for you to do a "select all" in the terminal window and copy everything to the clipboard, then start your program that reads from the clipboard?

Comment: @Philippos if the "select all" is done manually, then it's not a programmatic solution :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda it is a very similar question. it would be effectively duplicate if somebody knowledgeable would confirm that reading from the current terminal (asked in this question) is effectively the same (in other words, not generally possible) as reading from another terminal (asked in the proposed question).

Comment: @Marcus You don't need to do it manually, you can script it, using something like `xdotool` to send keystrokes to your terminal. If you can't copy the screen with keystrokes in gnome terminal, you can do it in a `screen` session and do a <Ctrl-A>`:hardcopy` there.

Comment: @Philippos if it can be scripted, in any form (eg. with xdotool as you mentioned), put a brief summary as answer, an I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a script using `screen` and `xdotool`.

This could be your `outputworker.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
$1
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+a colon h a r d c o p y space o u t p u t Return Return
your_command output
```

Then start `screen` and do `outputworker.sh command` the command gets executed, `<ctrl-a>:hardcopy output` and a return is sent to your `screen` session, producing a file called `output`, which you can use in your other program that works with the output.

**Edit**: The second `Return` keeps `screen` from waiting for a timeout while displaying the output from the hardcopy.

Comment: wow, if I can make this work, it's amazing. I will check it out and get back.